# What are all the ways to regain control of the execution thread in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dom-events, error-logging

I'm trying to enumerate the entry points from the browser to JavaScript code. This includes initial script execution (the trivial example), and all ways of regaining control of the main execution thread after relinquishing it.

- initial script execution
- event listeners, when not fired programmatically (`Node.addEventListener`, `DOMWindow.addEventListener`, `XMLHttpRequest.addEventListener`, all `object.oneventname` attributes)
- `setTimeout`
- `setInterval`

Are there any others I should consider?

(For the curious: the point of this is to wrap all entry points in `try...catch` blocks so that catching and logging errors on iOS is possible within a `UIWebView`. But it ought to be useful general information to have.)

Comment: How about `javascript:` URLs?

Comment: @Ates: That's a good one, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Web workers](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-workers/current-work/) are one other mechanism that can initiate callbacks.

Some browsers execute cross frame function calls in the event loop of the frame that created the function.  Others use a single event loop for all frames where such a thing is possible due to the same-origin policy.  I don't know about iOS though.

E.g.

```
window.parent.functionDefinedInParent();
```

Comment: +1 Thanks, especially for the frame discussion. Same-origin would keep javascript from cross-domain frames from directly accessing the other frame's members, so there is no reason for them to be in the same event loop. Wouldn't it be mandatory for browsers to operate same-origin frames on the same event loop?